# Broken pipe only at the second send on a closed socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client

I'm testing a client-server communication through a TCP socket. I wrote the server in C and I'm running it on a Linux machine and I'm using `nc` as a client for test.

The server, after an initial exchange of messages with the client, sends some
messages periodically to the client without getting any response.

If I kill the client, I expect that the first `send()` done by the server fails with
`EPIPE` error but this is turns out only at the second `send()` after the client has gone!
The first `send()` after I killed the client is able to successfully send 1100 bytes to the (I suppose closed) socket. The following `send()` operation ends with `EPIPE` as exepcted.

Is there someone who can explain me this behaviour?
Is it due to the fact that I write to the TCP/IP stack so it's up to the stack 
to deliver when it can?
If so, how can I check the connection status? To be sure the peer is still there.

Answer (score 4):

Normal TCP Connection is a four way handshake.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

When you are killing the client the **FIN** segment is sent from the client side to the server and the server protocol stack sends the **ACK**.

Here if the server tried to read data, the read call would return a value of 0, so your server program can understand that the peer has closed and normally would close the connection socket after this. This would allow the **FIN** from the server side to be sent and normal 4 way handshake would get completed after the receipt of the last **ACK** from the client side.

(Pl read Q 2.1 of http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/socket/)

But here you are writing data from the server, so the server is getting a **RESET** from the client only after sending data. So you are getting the error after the first send operation that is on the second send.

So, pl. try closing the connection from the client side **abruptly** instead of 4 way handshake, by setting the linger option and timeout to 0, so that you can get a error(may be different from EPIPE) on the first call of send on the server side.(This is not a recommended practice but only for your understanding in this particular case)

```
Try the following option of nc, nc -L 0 to set the linger option and timeout to 0
```

(I have not tried this option of nc, pl. check for details  in this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/nc-1.html)

Example of nc from the above site,

```
Connect to TCP port, send some data and terminate the connection with 
TCP RST segment 
(instead of classic TCP closing handshake) by setting the linger option and 
timeout to 0:

$ echo "foo" | nc -L 0 host.example.com 22
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, detailed and clear. Unfortunately I can't test the nc option you suggested me because the command on my Linux machine doesn't seem to support it. By the way the documentation you pointed me to and the explainations you gave me are clear and useful. Thanks!